# Java ExecutorCompletionService How know which task is returned

Tags: java, concurrency, executorservice

```
ExecutorService serv = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(5);
CompletionService<Integer> servive = new ExecutorCompletionService<>(serv);

for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
  servive.submit(new MyTask(i));
}

for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
  Future<Integer> f = null;
  try {
    f = servive.take();
  } catch (InterruptedException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
  }
  //f.get()
}
```

I want to know which task or callable was completed in the first result(`f.get()`)
How do I do that, or what other functions?

Comment: Why do you think you need to know which task was completed first? You could always change the `Future<Integer>` to something like `Future<TaskResult>` where `TaskResult` would contain information about the task as well as the return value.

Comment: If you can't tell them apart, then why does it matter?  If you _can_ tell them apart, then problem solved, right?  No!  Seriously!  Instead of returning `Integer`, why don't you return an object that contains an integer, and also contains whatever information you need to know about the task that produced the Integer?

Answer (score 0):

Well, its totally depends upon JVM and task how its going to be handle by JVM.